# wix toolset - How to make Directories permanent?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

My installer requires that I create some folders that cannot be uninstalled. Is there a way to make directories as permanent just like components?

For an empty folder, I am using below code and worked out successfully :-

```
<Directory Id="dir04517D319ACA03A67ABEF6DCD0061557" Name="paperworks">
     <Component Id="cmpC9B5254FDBE0CC06C0A860BF1CAE69E0" Guid="{A23C24A1-7FE5-4908-9739-AEBE3BCC7109}" KeyPath="yes" Permanent="yes">
        <CreateFolder />
      </Component>
   </Directory>
```

However, for a directory with files in it, how do I make that folder permanent?

Comment: Are these in the user profile or under program files? Windows Installer will not delete a file that is full of files, but it will delete it if all files are uninstalled. To leave it, use a CreateFolder entry in a dummy component with the directory as key path? Might work.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul .. Thank you for your response. The installed folder is in C:\ drive not in programs folder. My folder that needs to be installed has about 3000 files so I use heat.exe for harvesting which doesn't do what you recommended. Is there anything you could suggest to have heat create dummy components for folders? Reason being that when I am manually adding this dummy component, i get build errors saying an orphan entry has been found. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: `Directory` or `ComponentGroup` elements do not have the `Permanent` attribute. This means you cannot have a whole folder with the installed files set to permanent through one attribute. You can, however, perform an xsl transformation on your generated (from heat.exe) .wxs file and set every component to `Permanent = "yes"`